# How to extract all section headings in this web page?

Tags: html, jsoup

Using JSoup, I have been trying to select all h2 section-heading nodes (into an `Elements` list):

```
Elements sectionheadings = dom.doc.select("h2[class=section-heading collapsible-heading open-block]");
```

in this Wikipedia page:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana_cake

However, the result is always an empty list.

I know it is not empty because I can view it using Firebug. It even provides the exact full path to such heading:

> html.client-js
>   body.mediawiki.ltr.sitedir-ltr.stable.skin-minerva.action-view.animations
>   div#mw-mf-viewport div#mw-mf-page-center div#content
>   div#bodyContent.content.mw-content-ltr
>   h2.section-heading.collapsible-heading.open-block

What am I doing wrong?

What is the proper JSoup syntax for selecting all such h2 headings? (I can see at least 4 of them there)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to determine what `selector` to use is to print out the `html` document retrieved by `Jsoup` and inspect it. I have done this myself with your url and found out that:

- In the retrieved document, **h2 tags DO NOT have any attributes**

But how come when we inspect the website with Firebug there are attributes for `h2` tags? This is because the attributes are **generated by** ***JavaScript*** during website loading. Since `Jsoup` cannot crawl content generated by Javascript, it will retrieved the website content "as is" with pure `html` content.

**To sum up**: In your case you should be using:

```
Elements sectionheadings = dom.doc.select("h2");
```

Comment: Joel, thank you very much. I wish I could vote up your answer up but I don't have 15 points yet. Indeed using "h2" only without any attributes, returns non-empty `Elements` list. I now need to find a way to tell section headings h2's from other h2's (if present). Interestingly, when I inspect the HTML via `Developer` > `Page Source`, the same h2 has no attribute: `<h2><span class="mw-headline"`. Weird. I wonder why JavaScript generation no longer works in my program since I took care of terminating each such load with a `javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML(...)`.